# Libgdx InputListenner not working

Tags: java, libgdx

I've added an `InputListener` to my `libgdx` `actor` and I've added the `actor` to the `stage`. The `stage` (and all of its actors) gets drawn just fine.

The problem is my `actor` doesn't seem to be receiving keyboard inputs as nothing happens when I press keys.

```
@Override
public void show() {
 stage = new Stage();
 player = new Player();
 player.setPosition(600, 600);
 stage.setKeyboardFocus(player);
 player.addListener(new InputListener(){
   @Override
   public boolean keyDown(InputEvent event, int keyCode) {
    System.out.println("Key Down");
    return true;
   }
 });
 stage.addActor(player);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I hadn't set the `stage` as the [`InputProcessor`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html), so I did that `onShow()`:

```
@Override
public void show(){
 ...
 Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}
```

I also set it to null `onHide()` just in case:

```
@Override
public void hide(){
 ...
 Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that it has to be done in show(). I tried to do it in my Screen class's constructor and wondered why it didn't work. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Notice

```
int keyCode
```

Replace it with the key code of the key you want it to listen for.

Comment: I assumed `keyDown()` was meant to be used to catch keyboard inputs regardless of what key was being pressed?

Comment: Well I've not used libgdx, but it wouldn't accept a keyCode as a parameter if it wasn't meant for specific keys. I don't know how you'd get it to check for any un-specified key event though.